# onafterprint in iframe stopped firing in chrome when printing iframe?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, iframe

Has anybody else experienced that the onafterprint event does not fire in chrome when and iframe (not the whole page) is printed? Our customer reports it still worked in January. The onafterprint does not seem to fire for the main document nor for the iframe. I have `<body onafterprint="some_function()">` on the pages.

I tried running my test on browserstack and it seems to stop working in Chrome 88.

doc.html:

```
<html>
    <body style="background-color: #69D;" onafterprint="console.log('Main document onafterprint()');">
        <iframe src="oap.html" height="500" width="500"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

oap.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body onafterprint="afterprint()">

<h1><a href="javascript:window.print();">Click to print iframe</a></h1>

<script>
function afterprint() {
  console.log("iframe printed");
}

/* This fires in chrome */
            if (window.matchMedia) {
              var mediaQueryList = window.matchMedia('print');
              mediaQueryList.addListener(function(mql) {
                  if (mql.matches) {
                      console.log('before print');
                  } else {
                      console.log('afterprint');
                  }
              });
            }

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I found there is a work around for Chrome with matchMedia(). Seems to work good enough for me.

```
/* This fires in chrome */
            if (window.matchMedia) {
              var mediaQueryList = window.matchMedia('print');
              mediaQueryList.addListener(function(mql) {
                  if (mql.matches) {
                      console.log('before print');
                  } else {
                      console.log('afterprint');
                  }
              });
            }
```

Comment: You are a life saver, had trouble making `window.onafterprint` to work and the code above worked perfectly on google chrome version `Version 108.0.5359.99`. +1 vote